# How to create a reusable modal in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website using only JavaScript, HTML, and CSS *(no Bootstrap or jQuery)*.
I have used JavaScript to get the details of the cakes onto the page, as shown with the code below. 
Now, I am looking to create a button **"View recipes"** to view each cake using a modal.

Currently, the button appears outside of the box. I'm still pretty new to this and would appreciate any help on how to add in a button that opens a modal that displays different recipes for each box generated from the  `cakeData` instances.

The code below for each button and modal is hardcoded in HTML. I would like to refactor the HTML code for the button  over to `recipes.js` where it can be associated with the `cakeData` instances. I'm trying to condense the code down so I'm not copying and pasting code in HTML page, as I want to put 10+ cakes as the website progresses.

```js
// recipes.js
"use strict";

function buildCake(cake) {
  const article = document.createElement('article');
  article.classList.add('cake');
  const h4 = document.createElement('h4');
  h4.textContent = cake.name;
  article.appendChild(h4);
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = cake.description;
  article.appendChild(p);
  const image = document.createElement('img');
  image.src = cake.img;
  article.appendChild(image);
  return article;
}

const cakeData = [{
    name: "Chocolate Cake",
    img: "../img/chocolate-cake.jpg",
    description: "Gooey chocolate cake",
    button: ""
  },
  {
    name: "Chocolate Drip Cake",
    img: "../img/drip.jpg",
    description: "Chocolate layered sponge cake"
  },
  {
    name: "Victoria Sponge Cake",
    img: "../img/VSCake.jpg",
    description: "Airy sponge cake"
  },
  {
    name: "Fondant Cake",
    img: "../img/Aishteru.jpg",
    description: "Airy sponge cake with fondant"
  }
]

cakeData.forEach(loadCake);

function loadCake(cake) {
  const mycake = buildCake(cake);
  cakes.appendChild(mycake);
}

document.getElementById('cakes').appendChild(cake);

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

  if (target.hasAttribute('data-toggle') && target.getAttribute('data-toggle') == 'modal') {
    if (target.hasAttribute('data-target')) {
      var m_ID = target.getAttribute('data-target');
      document.getElementById(m_ID).classList.add('open');
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  // Close modal window with 'data-dismiss' attribute or when the backdrop is clicked
  if ((target.hasAttribute('data-dismiss') && target.getAttribute('data-dismiss') == 'modal') || target.classList.contains('modal')) {
    var modal = document.querySelector('[class="modal open"]');
    modal.classList.remove('open');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);

// scripts.js

"use-strict";

function toggleNav() {
  document.getElementById("sideNav").classList.toggle('open');
}
closeNav.addEventListener('click', toggleNav);
openNav.addEventListener('click', toggleNav);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FF7E41;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: blanchedalmond;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  /* Stay at the top */
  left: -100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  /* Stay on top */
  background-color: #FF9765;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 2s;
  opacity: 0.5;
  padding: 2px;
}

nav .menu,
.menu1 {
  text-align: right;
}

nav.open {
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 40px;
  align-content: right;
  opacity: 1;
}

nav a,
.menu,
.menu1 {
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  transition: 2s;
}

.menu {
  top: 0;
}

a {
  transition: 2s ease;
  padding: 2px;
}

main {
  width: 85% padding: 0px 30px;
}


/* recipes.html styles */

.cake-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

article.cake {
  border: 5px solid blanchedalmond;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 175px;
}


/* Popup Box */

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 9999;
}

.modal-window {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.modal-window.small {
  width: 30%;
}

.modal-window.large {
  width: 75%;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.open {
  display: block;
}

.btn {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span class="menu" id="openNav">&#9776;</span>
  <nav id="sideNav">
    <span class="menu1" id="closeNav">&times;</span>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="recipes.html">Recipes</a>
    <a href="ingredients.html">Ingredients</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
  </nav>
  <h1>Recipes</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <section id="cakes" class="cake-grid">
    <article id="cake">
      <p>
        <button data-target="simpleModal_1" data-toggle="modal" class="btn">View Recipe</button>
      </p>
      <div id="simpleModal_1" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-window">
          <h3>Chocolate cake</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <p>
        <button data-target="simpleModal_2" data-toggle="modal" class="btn">View Recipe</button>
      </p>
      <div id="simpleModal_2" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-window">
          <h3>Victoria sponge cake</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to target the .btn class. This class tells the document where to position the button. Of course, there are different ways to put the buttons inside the box. I would recommend reading this guide about CSS positioning. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position.

```js
// recipes.js
"use strict";

function buildCake(cake) {
  const article = document.createElement('article');
  article.classList.add('cake');
  const h4 = document.createElement('h4');
  h4.textContent = cake.name;
  article.appendChild(h4);
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = cake.description;
  article.appendChild(p);
  const image = document.createElement('img');
  image.src = cake.img;
  article.appendChild(image);
  return article;
}

const cakeData = [{
    name: "Chocolate Cake",
    img: "../img/chocolate-cake.jpg",
    description: "Gooey chocolate cake",
    button: ""
  },
  {
    name: "Chocolate Drip Cake",
    img: "../img/drip.jpg",
    description: "Chocolate layered sponge cake"
  },
  {
    name: "Victoria Sponge Cake",
    img: "../img/VSCake.jpg",
    description: "Airy sponge cake"
  },
  {
    name: "Fondant Cake",
    img: "../img/Aishteru.jpg",
    description: "Airy sponge cake with fondant"
  }
]

cakeData.forEach(loadCake);

function loadCake(cake) {
  const mycake = buildCake(cake);
  cakes.appendChild(mycake);
}

document.getElementById('cakes').appendChild(cake);

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

  if (target.hasAttribute('data-toggle') && target.getAttribute('data-toggle') == 'modal') {
    if (target.hasAttribute('data-target')) {
      var m_ID = target.getAttribute('data-target');
      document.getElementById(m_ID).classList.add('open');
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  // Close modal window with 'data-dismiss' attribute or when the backdrop is clicked
  if ((target.hasAttribute('data-dismiss') && target.getAttribute('data-dismiss') == 'modal') || target.classList.contains('modal')) {
    var modal = document.querySelector('[class="modal open"]');
    modal.classList.remove('open');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);

// scripts.js

"use-strict";

function toggleNav() {
  document.getElementById("sideNav").classList.toggle('open');
}
closeNav.addEventListener('click', toggleNav);
openNav.addEventListener('click', toggleNav);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FF7E41;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: blanchedalmond;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  /* Stay at the top */
  left: -100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  /* Stay on top */
  background-color: #FF9765;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 2s;
  opacity: 0.5;
  padding: 2px;
}

nav .menu,
.menu1 {
  text-align: right;
}

nav.open {
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 40px;
  align-content: right;
  opacity: 1;
}

nav a,
.menu,
.menu1 {
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  transition: 2s;
}

.menu {
  top: 0;
}

a {
  transition: 2s ease;
  padding: 2px;
}

main {
  width: 85% padding: 0px 30px;
}


/* recipes.html styles */

.cake-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

article.cake {
  border: 5px solid blanchedalmond;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 175px;
}


/* Popup Box */

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 9999;
}

.modal-window {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.modal-window.small {
  width: 30%;
}

.modal-window.large {
  width: 75%;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.open {
  display: block;
}

.btn {
position: relative;
left: -280px;
top: 100px;
background-color: blanchedalmond;
border: none;
color: black;
padding: 10px;
text-align: right;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span class="menu" id="openNav">&#9776;</span>
  <nav id="sideNav">
    <span class="menu1" id="closeNav">&times;</span>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="recipes.html">Recipes</a>
    <a href="ingredients.html">Ingredients</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
  </nav>
  <h1>Recipes</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <section id="cakes" class="cake-grid">
    <article id="cake">
      <p>
        <button data-target="simpleModal_1" data-toggle="modal" class="btn">View Recipe</button>
      </p>
      <div id="simpleModal_1" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-window">
          <h3>Chocolate cake</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <p>
        <button data-target="simpleModal_2" data-toggle="modal" class="btn">View Recipe</button>
      </p>
      <div id="simpleModal_2" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-window">
          <h3>Victoria sponge cake</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've had a look at the link. However this would still mean I need to repeat code in the html page. I'm looking for majority of the code to be in recipes.js

Comment: In that case, try to use the following:
                                                           document.getElementsByClassName("btn").style.top = "100px";
document.getElementsByClassName("btn").style.left = "-280px";
document.getElementByClassName("btn").style.position = "relative";